# How do I deploy a contained SQL Server database from Visual Studio / SQL Server Data Tools?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools

When creating a database project, in Visual Studio with SQL Server Data Tools, how do I define the database Containment Type property (or in fact, any other database-level property)?

When I look at the properties of the project I don't see anywhere where this can be defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click your Database Project and Select Properties. On the Project Settings Pane, click the <kbd>Database Settings...</kbd> button. Then go to the Miscellaneous pane. There is an option "Containment" and set this to "Partial".

[image]

Comment: brilliant - so simple when you know how! Searching the web strangely didn't turn up much!

Comment: If that option isn't available in the Miscellaneous pane (it wasn't in mine) then set the property in your .sqlproj manually:

<Containment>Partial</Containment>

Without that, I kept getting the error "ALTER DATABASE failed because a lock could not be placed on database" when Visual Studio 2022 tried to run the command 

ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
            SET CONTAINMENT = PARTIAL 
            WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;